# ColdFusion blank page in IE7 on refresh?

Tags: coldfusion, internet-explorer-7, refresh

I'm new to ColdFusion, have a very basic problem that's really slowing me down.

I'm making edits in a text editor and refreshing the page in web browsers for testing. Standard web dev stuff, no browser-sniffing, redirection, or other weirdness, and no proxies involved.

When I refresh the page in Chrome or Firefox, everything works fine, but when I refresh in IE7, I get a blank page. View Source shows me:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

That's it. While I am rendering to the transitional DTD, the *real* head contains a title, etc.

My development server is CF 9, production is 8. This problem has been happening in both. Seems it *may* only be happening on pages that are the the result of a POST action.

I've never experienced this in ASP.NET (my usual development environment) using the same browsers.

Comment: I can't think of any good reason for this to happen, other than IE7 being set to work offline or having some security settings which could cause this. Can you post your code so people can help you track down the issue?

Comment: If you haven't already, turn on debugging in the ColdFusion administrator (http://yourserver/cfide/administrator and choose  Debug Output Settings)

Comment: thats what IE shows as the source when the server returns nothing at all. I assume there is some sort of error that is not being sent to the browser, so as John Whish says, turn on debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, IE does not re-post forms on refresh by default.  It's been a few years since I used it for more than testing.  However, I also recall it giving a message like "this page has expired" or something similar, so this may not be the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using IIS - If so, just to make sure that you get a fresh version of the page every time, set the content expiration  (under HTTP headers in the site configuration) to "immediately"

Also, clear your IE cache and cookies... And, in CF admin, un-tick the "Enable HTTP status codes" option in the main setting page.